# External IP unreachable over web browser to GCP instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, wordpress, google-compute-engine

I created a [Wordpress website](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/imagesDetail/projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/wordpress-v20190715) on my GCP instance and it was assigned an external IP address automatically. I also have a static IP reserved for myself and I've assigned it to the instance.

I used to be able to connect to it initially and imported my previous website using the web browser and everything worked beautifully. However, now I cannot reach it any more over a web browser.

I ran a few commands to verify that there is a server listening on port 80:

```
root@xxxxxyyyzzzz-vm:~# netstat -tnlp | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1618/apache2
```

Also, SSH console opens and apache and MySQL processes are running:

```
root@xxxxxyyyzzzz-vm:~# ps -ef | grep apache
www-data  1618 15964  0 12:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  1619 15964  0 12:12 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      9108  8962  0 20:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep apache
root     15964     1  0 Aug30 ?        00:00:14 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28362 15964  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28363 15964  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28364 15964  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28365 15964  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28366 15964  0 06:25 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 28797 15964  0 06:46 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root@xxxxxyyyzzzz-vm:~# ps -ef | grep mysql
root      9122  8962  0 20:24 pts/0    00:00:00 grep mysql
mysql    16015     1  0 Aug30 ?        00:02:29 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Also, my firewall rules are open on both ports 80 and 443.

Why can't I connect to the instance over my browser?

Comment: Are you unable to reach your wordpress website after updating Dynamic to static IP? Is your DNS A record updated after the IP address changed?

Comment: @Milad - thanks for the response! I believe I had the static IP assigned when I reserved the instance and it was working fine.

Also, I just can't reach it over http://<IP Address> directly... let alone DNS lookups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so in my case I found a hacky way to solve this. Just created a duplicate VM instance, and reserved its ephemeral IP to static, and deleted the old instance.

Not a clean solution but better than remaining stuck forever :\